# TCP keepalive how does it work

Tags: tcp

I run on Ubuntu and i want to use TCP keepalive in order to implement hearbeat between master-slave.both servers are my impl (c++).
I read this [overview](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/) and did some google.
i didnt understand what TCP keepalive send and i do  know if connection is no longer valid when use in  TCP keepalive ?. Do i need to check the revived content?

The target is to have hearbeat between master-slave , so if one failed the other will be the master.
in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495922/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-heartbeat-in-c-to-check-for-socket-connect) the advice is to implement hearbeat with tcp keepalive mechanism, so this is the reason that i am asking how i identify the broken connection when using tcp keepalive.

Comment: First, please clarify your question. Are you asking about the [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) software for load balancing and high availability, or the TCP keepalive mechanism for holding open idle TCP connections (which you provided a link to)? These are two completely different things.

Comment: TCP keepalived.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my comment. The two are completely different things, and you've linked to a howto that doesn't address keepalived at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the TCP keepalive mechanism with a load balancing daemon called *keepalived*. The two have nothing to do with each other. And if you're trying to detect connection loss or problems between two programs, both of which you've written, you don't want either mechanism.

If you want to detect a bad connection between two programs when you've written both of them, just build dead connection detection into the code. TCP guarantees that a side that is sending will detect a dead connection. So the simplest solution is to ensure that both sides send periodically. Another solution is to ensure one side sends periodically and the other side declares the connection dead if it does not receive that periodic data.

Comment: I try to implmemt hearbeat between 2 process by using tcp keep alived. this was the advice in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495922/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-heartbeat-in-c-to-check-for-socket-connect

Comment: That suggestion was to use keepalive, not keepalived. Unfortunately, that's a terrible answer though. TCP keepalives should not be used for anything new, they're a compatibility workaround for legacy implementations.

Comment: [Here's a better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12570663/721269) to that question.